Docker image push failed with EOF / Broken Pipe / Closed Connection error
I've tried to push the docker images to the remote repository. But every operation gets failed.
Either I get EOF exception like below
My-MacBook-Pro-2 producer % docker push <awsAccountId>.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/producer:latest
The push refers to repository [<awsAccountId>.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/producer]
c7890551eec4: Waiting 
b32c59a2510d: Waiting 
3d898485473e: Waiting 
5b316a2cb183: Waiting 
a0ee1f650005: Waiting 
45dff4c2315c: Waiting 
failed to do request: Head "https://<awsAccountId>.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v2/producer/blobs/sha256:c7890551eec49eefdd40b2b56d0e2f2f575641ed7de0c1da92ad94d63311b449": EOF

Or broken pipe error like below
My-MacBook-Pro-2 producer % docker push <awsAccountId>.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/producer:latest
The push refers to repository [<awsAccountId>.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/producer]
3d898485473e: Pushing [==========>                                        ]  6.488MB/30.05MB
45dff4c2315c: Pushing [==================================================>]  1.566MB/1.566MB
a0ee1f650005: Layer already exists 
5b316a2cb183: Pushing [=>                                                 ]  5.636MB/195.2MB
c7890551eec4: Already exists 
b32c59a2510d: Pushing [===================>                               ]  6.783MB/17.82MB
failed to copy: failed to do request: Put "https://<awsAccountId>.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v2/producer/blobs/uploads/7127e92e-d7a7-4147-984e-3dbdf8f12f0f?digest=sha256%3A3d898485473e3507374cea2e09f019c2ff5728f0911aa36c70b7a7235e9bc8ac": write tcp 192.168.65.3:58604->192.168.65.1:3128: write: broken pipe

or Closed connection error like below
My-MacBook-Pro-2 producer % docker push <awsAccountId>.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/producer:latest
The push refers to repository [<awsAccountId>.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/producer]
a0ee1f650005: Layer already exists 
c7890551eec4: Already exists 
b32c59a2510d: Pushing [======================>                            ]   7.93MB/17.82MB
3d898485473e: Pushing [=============>                                     ]   7.93MB/30.05MB
5b316a2cb183: Pushing [==>                                                ]  7.864MB/195.2MB
45dff4c2315c: Pushed 
failed to copy: failed to do request: Put "https://<awsAccountId>.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v2/producer/blobs/uploads/1867b7ba-801e-473d-b876-3d605b084822?digest=sha256%3Ab32c59a2510d79e17fa6c4c4598df1fa2a9d03967a435984e9fd8231d9d7b541": write tcp 192.168.65.3:59342->192.168.65.1:3128: use of closed network connection

I'm having good network connection and attached an image for reference. Also the user has proper permissions to push the image to ECR. I'm facing the same problem if i try to push an image to docker hub.
Docker details
My-MacBook-Pro-2 producer % docker version
Client:
 Version:           26.1.4
 API version:       1.45
 Go version:        go1.21.11
 Git commit:        5650f9b
 Built:             Wed Jun  5 11:26:02 2024
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           desktop-linux

Server: Docker Desktop 4.31.0 (153195)
 Engine:
  Version:          26.1.4
  API version:      1.45 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.21.11
  Git commit:       de5c9cf
  Built:            Wed Jun  5 11:29:12 2024
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.33
  GitCommit:        d2d58213f83a351ca8f528a95fbd145f5654e957
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.12
  GitCommit:        v1.1.12-0-g51d5e94
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0

I got stuck into this issue for 2 days. Can someone help me how to debug this and remediate from this problem?
Regarding the size of image, I'm just trying to run a basic spring boot app in docker. It won't exceed 200 MB
Dockerfile Info
FROM openjdk:19-jdk-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY target/*-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]

My image has to be pushed to the remote repository. But it is not pushed even though the user has proper permissions and I'm having good network connection

Did you try restarting your docker daemon?

Yes, I did. I have even reinstalled docker multiple times

What if you try to build another image and push it to Docker free registry? Does it work? Just try building a simply python Image that install minimalistic requirements.txt.
